# How To Display Content from a website on wordpress page?

Tags: embed

So, I have been working on a gaming website for a long time.

There are similar sites as mine made with Wordpress, but they display alerts of the game (fetched from other website).

For example - freethevbucks.com/timed-missions/

This page is displaying information from this URL stormshield.one/pve/

Is it possible to replicate the same thing, I mean it obviously is. But I always have been wondering how this is done?

Comment: with PHP you can read the result of a HTTP GET request with https://secure.php.net/file_get_contents and then parse the datas.

Answer (score 2):

Although CURL requests will work, you should use `wp_remote_post(`) to do requests to external pages, especially if you are writing a plugin or theme. (Plugin review doesn't like CURL requests; they will ask you to convert to `wp_remote_post()`.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post . The return value includes the header and all content of the request. You can then parse that return value as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with curl, e.g.

```
add_shortcode('get_curl_content', function ($args) {
    $ret = '';
    if (!empty($args['url']) && filter_var($args['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        $ch = curl_init($args['url']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        // extract some content from $html using DOMDocument or regex
        // $ret = 'Your extracted content';
    }
    return $ret;
});
```

Use the shortcode like this in your post:

`[get_curl_content url="https://url-to-scrape.com"]`

Edit: Using `wp_remote_post` instead of `curl`

As we are in WordPress, `wp_remote_post` is the more proper approach:

```
add_shortcode('get_curl_content', function ($args) {
    $ret = '';
    $remote = wp_remote_post($args['url']);
    if (is_array($remote) && isset($remote['body'])) {
        // extract some content from $remote['body'] using DOMDocument or regex
        // $ret = 'Your extracted content';
    }
    return $ret;
});
```